# Get fps using ffmpeg in java without ProcessBuilder or Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am working with [ffmpeg_wrapper](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper) and I want to get frames per second(fps) of a video. The command which can be used to do it is:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fps.*/\1/p"
```

which is giving me output:
`24`

But the issue is I was not able to find any way to do this as java code. Please note, I don't want to use ProcessBuilder or Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), as they would start an another process.

I also had a usecase to capture the screenshot from the video for which I wrote this code:

```
public void captureScreenshots(String videoPath, String outputPath, int intervalInSeconds) {
        FFmpeg ffmpeg = null;
        try {
            ffmpeg = new FFmpeg();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        int videoFrameRate=getFrameRate(videoPath);
        int frameInterval=videoFrameRate*intervalInSeconds;

        String videoFilter="select='not(mod(n,24))',setpts='N/(24*TB)'";

        FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
                .setInput(videoPath)
                .addOutput(outputPath)
                .setVideoFilter(videoFilter)
                .setFormat("image2")
                .done();

        FFmpegExecutor executor = null;
        try {
            executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        executor.createJob(builder).run();
```

And this kind of similar way I want to do for getting fps. Can anyone help?

Comment: What library and version are you using for ffmpeg in Java? What is the result of the code? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @aled I am using the library ffmpeg bramp cli wrapper.. i already attached the link in the first line as hyperlink too. The version I didn't provided which is 0.8.0. and the first command which I gave you I want to code it in Java using the library I told. And the code which I provided I gave is given to help that this is how there is support from this package for screenshot part but for getting fps there is no support in wrapper package, just I can do it with terminal. But I need to do it with Java code instead of running this command directly with Java code

Comment: *Please note, I don't want to use ProcessBuilder or Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), as they would start an another process.* You realize that the library you're attempting to use does exactly that..?

Comment: @g00se I didn't check the code internally, if it is doing the same, bad thing, but atleast I would be getting the error response or handling properly with it. I won't have to make anything from scratch. Do you have any way to do it in this library, or i shall use another library (won't encourage that as I have came a bit far in this)

Comment: Incase someone is looking for the screenshot part of the which I have added above, in combination with @g00se code(which is the accepted answer), please not that the code wont work if the fps is a double value(eg 29.97 or somthing), whereas it works fine when it is an int value(say 24,30 et). Hence, amke sure to convert it to a rounded off value is Math.round() before using it in String videoFilter="select='not(mod(n,24))',setpts='N/(24*TB)'";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adapt the code sample at the Github site of that API, the line added by me shows the frame rate:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import net.bramp.ffmpeg.probe.FFmpegFormat;
import net.bramp.ffmpeg.probe.FFmpegProbeResult;
import net.bramp.ffmpeg.probe.FFmpegStream;
import net.bramp.ffmpeg.FFprobe;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("/usr/bin/ffprobe");
        FFmpegProbeResult probeResult = ffprobe.probe("input.mp4");

        FFmpegFormat format = probeResult.getFormat();
        System.out.format("%nFile: '%s' ; Format: '%s' ; Duration: %.3fs", format.filename, format.format_long_name,
                format.duration);

        FFmpegStream stream = probeResult.getStreams().get(0);
        System.out.format("%nCodec: '%s' ; Width: %dpx ; Height: %dpx", stream.codec_long_name, stream.width, stream.height);
        System.out.format("%nAverage frame rate: %.2f%n", stream.avg_frame_rate.doubleValue());

    }
}
```